# Binding all textures on one huge descriptor set

Tags: binding, textures, vulkan

I have some design qustion for a vulkan game engine:

In my game engine i bound all "static" textures resources on one huge descriptor-set(256k descriptors), and my shaders access those samplers by an dynamic indexing.
[For example when i want to sample a some normals-map that belong to a currtain gameobject i add an new uint into the material's ubo that represent the index of the object's normals-map descriptor inside the huge descriptor set, then i sample it and compute the final object color.]

I wondered whether this way to access objects textures is efficient compare to the idia to bind each object's texture on his per-object descriptor set(alongside the material ubo).

Does the size of an descriptor-set can drastically affect on the texel access speed?
or my idia is suck?

Again, sorry about my English.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are no performance issues with indexing from an array of sampler descriptors. The only real reason not to do things this way is that implementations may not let you dynamically index such arrays. But if you're requiring that from the implementation (all desktop implementations allow it), then just keep doing it; it's a common technique for reducing the number of state changes you have to issue on the CPU.

Comment: Ok thanks for respond again, its perfect for me. but if i want in addition to bind images that used as color attachments on this huge descriptor the validation layer will start to yell at me again - according to the previous discussion here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70689903/binding-images-without-using-them-all-in-vulkan . So am i have to create a saperate descriptor sets for those images or its acceptable just to ignore the validation layer when i not actually useing sampler of the image that i write into in the renderpass?